# What caused the "No property find found for type" spring data jpa error

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

the error
No property find found for type com.gridsearch.entities.Film

my repository

```
package com.gridsearch.repository;


    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    import com.gridsearch.entities.Film;
    public interface FilmRepository extends CrudRepository<Film,Short>{

        public Page<Film> findAll(Pageable page);
        public Film findOne(short Id);

     }
```

my service

```
package com.gridsearch.service;


import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import com.gridsearch.entities.Film;

public interface FilmService {
    public Page<Film> allFilms(Pageable page);
    public Film findOne(int Id);

}
```

my service implementation

```
package com.gridsearch.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.gridsearch.entities.Film;
import com.gridsearch.repository.FilmRepository;

@Repository
public class FilmServiceImpl implements FilmService{
    @Autowired
    private FilmRepository repository;
    @Transactional
    public Page<Film> allFilms(Pageable page) {
        return  repository.findAll(page);

    }
    @Override
    public Film findOne(int id) {
        return repository.findOne((short) id);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `Short` instead of `short`:

```
public Film findOne(Short Id);
```

By the way , you can simply extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` which already provides the method `findAll(Pageable page)`:

```
public interface FilmRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Film,Short>{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has been answered but I got the same problem because I left an old method in my repository like

```
public List<Entity> findByDateBetween(Long a, Long b)
```

while "date" column didn't exist anymore in my database.